# Dynamic LINQ Language Function

Tags: .net, linq

Hy there,

This is my first question here in stackoverflow, I hope you can help me.

I have the following property filled in a linq query:

```
FieldLabel = (currentLanguage == "de" ? forum.language.German :
         currentLanguage == "fr" ? forum.language.French :
         currentLanguage == "en" ? forum.language.English :
         forum.language.English)
```

And i need this to be generic, as my "forum" entity can be other thing like "post" that has the some languages columns (German, French, English), etc.
I want some dynamic method that receives the entity type, like "forum" or "post" or anything else that has columns languages, and returns the choosen column based on that chained If.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4.0 or higher and all of your entities have the 'language' property, you could use the [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) keyword:

```
private dynamic GetLanguage(String currentLanguage, dynamic entity)
{
    return (currentLanguage == "de" ? entity.language.German :
     currentLanguage == "fr" ? entity.language.French :
     currentLanguage == "en" ? entity.language.English :
     entity.language.English);
}
```

Comment: With your solution I get the following error:
"An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation"

Comment: I was expecting an string, so I changed your code to return a string and it works fine!
Tks

Comment: Now i need to something like, if the choosen column(based on currentLanguage) has no value, choose default column, in this case English.

Comment: Something like:
(case when [french] is null then [english] else [french] end) as language